# OBIEE 12 c RCU installation stuck on DB connection

Tags: oracle, virtual-machine, middleware, business-intelligence, obiee

I am trying to install OBIEE 12c on DB 12c using a VM box.
I have finished all perquisites steps and stuck on RCU step when entering connection parameters.

**Here is the error message:**

[image]

**Here's my tsnames and listener ora files**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: 

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = x.x.x.x)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: 

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = x.x.x.x)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\xxxx\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\xxxx\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    
  )
```

Comment: have you checked that you can actually access the database using different tools? ex: sqldeveloper